# Regex-based method needed that extracts indirectly defined variable names in non-es6-javascript string

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-5

I have a String containing indirectly referenced variabled:

```
var myString = "An ${art} is a ${bird} in an ${tree}"
```

I want to extract the variable names in an array:

```
getArray(myString); // song, bird, condition
```

or, even better, to replace this variables with corresponding properties of an object:

```
replace(myString,{art: "song", bird: "sparrow", tree: "oak"}); 
// A song is a sparrow in an oak
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function replace(mystring, dict)
{
    let regex = /\${([^}]+)}/g;
    return mystring.replace(regex, function(match, p1) {return dict[p1];});
}

var myString = "An ${art} is a ${bird} in an ${tree}";

console.log(replace(myString,{art: "song", bird: "sparrow", tree: "oak"}));
```

[See demo](http://ideone.com/4bw4Z5)